# Difference between WeakSet<T> and Set<Weakref<T>>

Tags: javascript, typescript, weak-references

I was recently wondering if there is any drawback for `Set<Weakref<T>>` over `WeakSet<T>`.

Pros:

- The set is iterable

Cons:

- The set must be filtered from no longer valid references

Am I missing something or is this almost a win-win situation? Would the `Set<Weakref<T>>` version prevent the garbage collector from collecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed:

> WeakSets are collections of objects only. They cannot contain
> arbitrary values of any type, as Sets can.
>
> The number of objects or their traversal order is immaterial, so a
> WeakSet is more suitable (and performant) than a Set for tracking
> object references, especially if a very large number of objects is
> involved.
>
> [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet)

`Set<Weakref<T>>` will not prevent GC. Also note that `WeakRef` is not supported in Opera but `WeakSet` is.

Comment: Superb! I do not understand what the `order is immaterial` means. I understand that dereferencing the variables is not ideal for performance, but the phrase seems to be talking about something different too.